# This property cannot be set after writing has started! on a C# WebRequest Object using GCM

Tags: c#, android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send data from c# to GCM , but I take this bug.

**code is here:**

```
 WebRequest tRequest;
    tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
    tRequest.Method = "post";
    tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
```

### tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

```
 con.Open();
            //int ekleyen_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["kullaniciId"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from users", con);
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rd.Read()) {
                string regIdSend = rd["registered_id"].ToString();
                // string postData = "{ 'registration_id': [ '" + regId + "' ], 'data': {'message': '" + txtMsg.Text + "'}}";
                string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + regIdSend + "";
                Console.WriteLine(postData);
                Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();

                WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

                dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

                //lblStat.Text = sResponseFromServer;
                tReader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                tResponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reuse the webrequest. You should create your webrequest inside the while loop.

Comment: thanks Its not giving error now but cloud cannot send notification my device . thanks